sqlmodel ValueError: <class 'list'> has no matching SQLAlchemy type
Given these classes and 1-to-N relationships, I get compile time error: ValueError: <class 'list'> has no matching SQLAlchemy type referring to the category.py field todos: list["Todo"], while the relation hero/team does work.
I also tried to replace the UUID type and use int in both classes, without success.
# hero.py (works)
class Hero(SQLModel, table=True):
    id: int | None = Field(default=None, primary_key=True)
    ....

    team_id: int | None = Field(default=None, foreign_key="team.id")
    team: Team | None = Relationship(back_populates="heroes")


# team.py (works)
class Team(SQLModel, table=True):
    id: int | None = Field(default=None, primary_key=True)
    .....

    heroes: list["Hero"] = Relationship(back_populates="team")


# todo.py (does not work)
class Todo(SQLModel, table=True):

    id: UUID | None = Field(
        default=uuid4(),
        primary_key=True,
    )

    ......

    category_id: UUID | None = Field(default=None, foreign_key="category.id")
    category: Category | None  = Relationship(back_populates="todos")


# category.py  (does not work => ValueError: <class 'list'>)
class Category(SQLModel, table=True):
    id: UUID | None = Field(default=uuid4(), primary_key=True)
    .....

    todos: list["Todo"] = Relationship(back_populates="category")

Full error log:
import todo.models.category
  File ".../todo/models/category.py", line 9, in <module>
    class Category(SQLModel, table=True):
  File ".../lib/python3.12/site-packages/sqlmodel/main.py", line 559, in __new__
    col = get_column_from_field(v)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "../lib/python3.12/site-packages/sqlmodel/main.py", line 708, in get_column_from_field
    sa_type = get_sqlalchemy_type(field)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "../lib/python3.12/site-packages/sqlmodel/main.py", line 697, in get_sqlalchemy_type
    raise ValueError(f"{type_} has no matching SQLAlchemy type")
ValueError: <class 'list'> has no matching SQLAlchemy type


I'm guessing SQLModel doesn't handle the list function as typing, but expects List (from typing).

I have check FastAPI docs and found a note:
Notice that the relationship attributes, the ones with Relationship(), are only in the table models, as those are the ones that are handled by SQLModel with SQLAlchemy and that can have the automatic fetching of data from the database when we access them.
class TeamBase(SQLModel):
    name: str = Field(index=True)
    headquarters: str


class Team(TeamBase, table=True):
    id: int | None = Field(default=None, primary_key=True)

    heroes: list["Hero"] = Relationship(back_populates="team")


class HeroBase(SQLModel):
    name: str = Field(index=True)
    secret_name: str
    age: int | None = Field(default=None, index=True)

    team_id: int | None = Field(default=None, foreign_key="team.id")


class Hero(HeroBase, table=True):
    id: int | None = Field(default=None, primary_key=True)

    team: Team | None = Relationship(back_populates="heroes")

I think you should try to split your model into two classes: SQLModel for DB fields and table models for relationship and check again. Hope you can fix this!

I don't think is needed, since the Hero/Team relation already works.
